# Class Diagram for Train-Wagon Senario

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have doubts on approaching doing this.

I have a Train class and a Wagon class. There are three types of wagon: FirstClass, TouristClass and DiningCar. Each of these types has the same properties and methods, the only difference between them is their multiplicity with the Train class.

Each train class has one and only one DiningCar wagon, at least one FirstClass wagon and at least one TouristClass wagon.

What is the best way to do this. Should the classes FirstClass, TouristClass and DiningCar inherit from the Wagon class, make them empty and then relate them to the train class? Or there is other approach?

Comment: Please, read this before anything else -> https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: What does the word "best" mean in this context?  Easiest to code?  Easiest to extend? Easiest to read?

Comment: If they really all behave the same, then why make them separate classes at all?  You say you _have_ these classes...  Well, why?  Presumably, you want to write code that uses them somehow.  What will that code do?  Using the language's type system to model relationships in your problem domain is not always the best way to proceed.

Comment: A minimalist solution is one car class that takes a string that says what kind of car it is. You did say the only difference was how many.

Comment: Isn't it sad when so many (most?) UML questions here come from university (assignment) context as opposed to real-world use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't provide the diagram because this is obviously some kind of homework. But here some hints:

**The basics**

> Each train class has one and only one `DiningCar` wagon, at least one
>   `FirstClass` wagon and at least one `TouristClass` wagon.

First, intuitively, `DiningCar`, `FirstClass` and `TouristClass` offer different services and behaviors.  For example, you wouldn't expect  `FirstClass` to offer a function `getNumberOfFreeRestaurantTables()`, while you would expect `DiningCar` to do.  So [specializing](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams) the `Wagon` seems a good idea.

> Each train class has one and only one ... at least one ...
>   and at least one ....

You have to translate this into [associations](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) between Train and your specialized `Wagon` classes. For each association you can specify the [multiplicity](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html).

**The more elaborate**

As there is a whole-part association between `Train` and its `Wagons`, you may consider using an [aggregation](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html?context=class-diagrams) instead of a normal association.

As a wagon could be removed from one train and attached to another train, we could assume that aggregation is the correct alternative, and that [composition](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams) would not suit the needs.

**Are there other approaches ?**

Sure !  You could not specialize `Wagon`, and let `Wagon` have some property that tells if which kind it is.

The aggregation association between `Train` and `Wagon` should then have a multiplicity telling that there are at least 3 `Wagons` (one of each).

But how would you then express that there is exactly one `DiningCar` at at least on of each of the other kind ?  Well, you could consider writing a [constraint](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html?context=class-diagrams) for the association.  The OCL expression to express this constraint formally is however much less self-explanatory than our initial approach with specialization...